# Can not deserialize instance of java.util.List out of VALUE_STRING

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm developing an application where I want to send some data to a server and get the response. The format I should use is the following.

```
{
   "userName" :"testuser2@test.com",
   "targetUserName":"janagan.h@gmail.com",
   "admin":"false",
   "privilege": [{ "site":1, "privileges": ["LIVE_FEED","PLAYBACK"] } ] 
}
```

The data I should send is populated by javascript and is sent to a PHP function where I use curl to send the request to the server. Following is the function which I use to send the request.

```
function baloba_update_user_priviledges(){
    if( isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['is_admin']) && isset($_POST['privArray']) ){


    $data = array('userName' => $_SESSION['user'], 'targetUserName' => $_POST['username'], 'privilege' => stripslashes($_POST['privArray']), 'admin' => $_POST['is_admin']);

    echo json_encode($data);


    $ch = 'https://54.169.242.241:8243/service_management_api/1.0/services/usermanage/assign_privilege';
    $responseData = baloba_api_requset($data ,$ch);
    extract($responseData);

    if($status == 'SUCCESS'){
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'SUCCESS', 'message' => $message ),TRUE);
        die();
    }
}
```

}

I used `echo` to view what is being set to the `$data` array. Which is the following.

```
{"userName":"testuser2@test.com","targetUserName":"testuser1@test.com","privilege":"[{\"site\":\"a0626000000HnwdAAC\",\"privileges\":[\"LIVE_FEED\",\"PLAYBACK\"]}]","admin":"false"}
```

When I send this array to the server it returns the following error.

```
HTTP Status 400 - org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.List out of VALUE_STRING token
at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@5ba88001; line: 1, column: 71]
```

The javascript which use to generate the data is as following.

```
function saveUserPriviledges(username,privArray){
    return  $.ajax({
                type    : 'POST',
                url     : '/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                data    : { action: "baloba_update_user_priviledges", 'username' : username, 'is_admin' : false , 'privArray' : JSON.stringify(privArray) },
            });
}

function saveUserPriviledgeHandler(username,privArray){
    $.when(saveUserPriviledges(username,privArray)).then(function(response){
        console.log(JSON.parse(response));
    })
}

function priviledgeObjCreator(siteId,privArray){
    return { 'site':siteId , 'privileges':privArray }
}

$(document).on('click','.save-priv-changes',function(){
        var privObjArray = [];
        var priv = [];
        var user = $('#userPriv').data('priv-current-user')

        $('#userPriv .tab-pane').each(function(e,tab){
            $(tab).find('.cmn-toggle:checked').each(function(i,el){
                priv.push($(el).attr('id').replace('cmn-toggle-',''));
            })
            privObjArray.push(priviledgeObjCreator(tab.id.replace('user-priv-',''),priv));
        })

        saveUserPriviledges(user,privObjArray)

})
```

What am I doing wrong here.! I used `stripslashes` function in php too. But I couldn't generate the necessary request string. how Can I make the request in the same format.? I understand that when I send the correct request format that it is successful and there is no error in the java code since the error is on java side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should strip slashes first then use `html_entity_decode` which removes all encoding from the `POST` and then decode the json string to the original array. Following is an example.

`json_decode(html_entity_decode(stripslashes($_POST['privArray'])))`